# beforeClass test method running twice Testng

Tags: java, testng

In the below example before class method is running twice. Is it the expected behavior? Because beforeClass is supposed to run only once before the first method in class runs. But in my class it runs twice.

```
package test;

import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;

public class Sample1
{ 

 @BeforeSuite
 public void setUp()
 {
     System.out.println("This is before suite");
 }

 @BeforeTest
 public void init()
 {
     System.out.println("This is before Test");
 }

 @BeforeClass
 public void t1()
 {
     System.out.println("This is before class");
 }

 @BeforeMethod
 public void t3()
 {
     System.out.println("This is before Method");
 }


  @AfterMethod
  public void t4()
  {
     System.out.println("This is After Method");
  }

  @AfterClass
  public void t2()
  {
     System.out.println("This is After class");
  }

  @AfterTest
  public void cleanUp()
  {
     System.out.println("This is After Test");
  }

  @AfterSuite
  public void tearDown()
  {
     System.out.println("This is after suite");
  }

}

package test;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Sample2 extends Sample1 {

  @Test
  public void f() 
  {
      System.out.println("This is the testmethod1 in Sample2");
  }

  @Test
  public void tets1 () 
  {
      System.out.println("This is the testmethod2 in Sample2");
  }

}

<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1" >

  <test name="Regression1"   >
  <classes>
  <class name="test.Sample2">
  <methods>
  <include name = "f" />
  </methods>
  </class>
  </classes>
  </test>

  <test name="Regression2"   >
  <classes>
  <class name="test.Sample2">
  <methods>
  <include name = "tets1" />
  </methods>
  </class>
  </classes>
  </test>

</suite>

/* Output is below -- after and before class running twice

This is before suite
This is before Test
This is before class
This is before Method
This is the testmethod1 in Sample2
This is After Method
This is After class
This is After Test
This is before Test
This is before class
This is before Method
This is the testmethod2 in Sample2
This is After Method
This is After class
This is After Test
This is after suite

*/
```

Comment: I would discourage using inheritance for any part of your test suite, period.  It makes the test less clear, and [can have other negative impacts as well.](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/unit-testing/3-reasons-why-we-should-not-use-inheritance-in-our-tests/)

Answer (score 1):

You get that behavior because your `<suite>` XML runs the two test methods as independent tests. If you allowed a single test to run both methods, then they would run on the same class instance, and `@BeforeClass` would only run once.